# Use pipes and awk to write a one-line program

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, pipe

I am stuck on a homework problem that requires me to write a shell script that does the following

- calculates the number of subdirectories in .
- calculates the number of files in . and its subdirectories
- calculates the sum size of all files in . and its subdirectories
- lists the top 5 biggest files in . and its subdirectories

IN ONE LINE.
I have one-line commands for each of the above points, but I am completely lost as to how to write the entire program in one line. My professor advised me to use awk but I still can not figure out a way to do this.

Here is the script so far:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Calculate the number of directories in .
ls -l . | grep -c ^d

# Calculate the number of files in .
ls -l . | egrep -c '^-'

# Calculate the sum size of all files in .
ls -Cl | awk '{ sum += $5 } END { print sum }'

# List the top 5 biggest files in .
find . -type f | xargs ls -lSh | head -n 5
```

Comment: It is always recommended NOT to parse output of `ls`, you could use search functionality on SO and look for `find` command's help.

Comment: That's true, but I'm wondering if the teacher isn't expecting students to have an `awk` command process the output of `ls -lr` to output the 5 required informations. The one-liner requirement is already pretty bad practice after all.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Anyway the easy way out would be to put your 5 commands in one line, separated by `;` rather than linefeeds. Can't say whether it would go against the spirit of the question, which I have a hard time guessing.

Comment: Hint: `ls -l | awk '/^d/ { dirs +=1 } /^-/ { files += 1 } ... END { print "files: ", files; print "dirs:", dirs; ... }'` Forcing the Awk script to be all on a single physical line is egregiously unfriendly but the *computer* doesn't mind. (And yes, eventually abandon `ls`.)

Answer (score 0):

## Calculate the number of directories in .

ls -dR |wc -l

## Calculate the number of files in .

ls -l|grep -v "^d"|wc -l

## Calculate the sum size of all files in .

du -sh .

## List the top 5 biggest files in .

du -sh *|sort -ar|head 5